# How can I add nested transactions in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a use case where I am processing multiple configuration within a function, each configuration processing runs within a separate transaction and transaction gets commited if everything is fine, now if at all anything goes wrong in processing of further configuration I want to revert all the commuted transaction. Can anyone please help me with code snippet? My application is on .net.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, NH doesn't support nested [transactions](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions).

You can use a transaction at the root of your use case, or at any point along the way, but it's all or nothing, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of using nested transactions. It's a matter of ensuring that you have a transaction that surrounds all the relevant code - so it should be open/closed "higher up". Each individual section should then either not care about transactions at all, or it should "piggy-back" on any existing transaction and only open a new transaction when one does not already exist.

As a guideline, transaction management is an overall concern that should be handled in different sorts of wrapper methods and applied as needed by the application - not hidden away in specific low-level support routines.